# Spring data - JPA : issue query with DTO and IF statement

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am trying to make a query that would build a DTO object :

```
@Query("Select new com.mycorp.rh.web.rest.dto.AnalyseProductionDTO(a.client.name, IF(a.salarie,'yes','no'))   
from Activity a where a.year = ?1 and a.month = ?2")
        List<AnalyseProductionDTO> getAnalyseProduction(Year year, Month month);
```

It doesn't work when I put a IF statement in the query.
I am getting a

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query

It works when I do :

```
@Query("Select new com.mycorp.rh.web.rest.dto.AnalyseProductionDTO(a.client.name, 'yes')   
from Activity a where a.year = ?1 and a.month = ?2")
        List<AnalyseProductionDTO> getAnalyseProduction(Year year, Month month);
```

Isn't it possible to include an IF statement in a constructor used in a query?

Comment: What is `salarie` for kind of field?

Comment: Can't you just pass salary in the constructor adding check inside the DTO?

Comment: it's a boolean (bit(1) in mysql)

Comment: StanislavL  yes i can, but I am curious about why it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 2):

By default `@Query` doesn't allow native queries. The query should be either HQL if the ORM is hibernate or anything that is supported by the underlying ORM.

Since IF() function is native to MySQL and not supported by ORM query languages its validation will fail.

You can try the following with `@Query.nativeQuery` set to `true`.

```
@Query(value = "Select new com.mycorp.rh.web.rest.dto.AnalyseProductionDTO(a.client.name, IF(a.salarie,'yes','no'))   
from Activity a where a.year = ?1 and a.month = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
```